# .net Session Time Out and Kendo Popup Window

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I use a popup window for edit operations using the Kendoui framework.

When a session times out while the popup is open the login page will load inside of the popup window.

I would like to add js in the forms redirect page and check if it is being loaded inside a popup window and if so redirect and close the window.

Is there a way to determine if a page is loaded inside of a popup and if so how can I get a handle to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the page is not redirected to the login page until you click button or do something.
We had the same problem and we solved it using Ajax call for our popup.
So we had some button on the popup and we read the response from the server. If the session is already expired you will have the wrong response code (not 200 definitely). You can read and interpret it and in your JS close popup window and do redirect to the login page like:

```
window.location = login_url
```

Comment: I did think of something similiar...Have a test function prior to each submit or cancel and check if the session is alive. I was just hoping I piggyback of of the redirect and close "any" dialog that may be open at that time.

Comment: Actually it depends how is your popup is organized. If it just have the some information that is not taken from the server, it's not a problem. The session expiration is only visible when you're trying to ask the server. Or if you want to tell the user about the expiration you can check the server all the time for example every 10 mins and read the result and show some message.

Comment: In this application I do not need to inform the user that session has quit in modal or page view. So the redirect is fine. I would like to know if I could determine if the login page is being displayed in a window --> "kendow popup window" and if so redirect and close the window. That would solve all my issues. If not, perhaps I should try what you have outlined.

Comment: The login page is being displayed only if some activity is done and you can't know this one if there is no any activity on the page so you don't need to wait until it's displayed, it's enough to know that request to the server returns some specific wrong value.